# What is the most memory-efficient way of downscaling images on iOS?

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-graphics, javax.imageio, cgimage

In background thread, my application needs to read images from disk, downscale them to the size of screen (1024x768 or 2048x1536) and save them back to disk. Original images are mostly from the Camera Roll but some of them may have larger sizes (e.g. 3000x3000).

Later, in a different thread, these images will frequently get downscaled to different sizes around 500x500 and saved to the disk again.

This leads me to wonder: what is the most efficient way to do this in iOS, performance and memory-wise? I have used two different APIs:

- using [`CGImageSource` and `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5860390/458193) from ImageIO;
- [drawing to `CGBitmapContext`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/c609027314be09f598d2a2a75192b10f89bf1e95/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDecoder.m) and saving results to disk with `CGImageDestination`.

Both worked for me but I'm wondering if they have any difference in performance and memory usage.  And if there are better options, of course.

Comment: I have done it "the old fashioned way" -- by bit twiddling -- as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052188/high-quality-scaling-of-uiimage).  The techniques there could probably be used to do the scaling in "chunks", to avoid overcommitting memory, but it's a little work.  (Not all that mysterious, though.)

Comment: have you looked at results of both your approaches in Instruments?

Comment: @foggzilla: No, I didn't have the time yet. I started a bounty hoping somebody would do the research.

Answer (score 7):

While I can't definetly say it will help, I think it's worth trying to push the work to the GPU. You can either do that yourself by rendering a textured quad at a given size, or by using [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and its resizing capabilities. While it has some texture size limitations on older devices, it *should* have much better performance than CPU based solution

Comment: GPUImage method is very memory much-consuming

Answer (score 5):

With libjpeg-turbo you can use the `scale_num` and `scale_denom` fields of `jpeg_decompress_struct`, and it will decode only needed blocks of an image. It gave me 250 ms decoding+scaling time in background thread on 4S with 3264x2448 original image (from camera, image data placed in memory) to iPhone's display resolution. I guess it's OK for an image that large, but still not great.

(And yes, that is memory efficient. You can decode and store the image almost line by line)

Comment: Hi, are you aware of any sample ObjC/iOS source code using libjpeg-turbo?

Comment: I guess I found [an example](https://github.com/dhoerl/PhotoScrollerNetwork/blob/master/PhotoScroller/Classes/TiledImageBuilder%2BJPEG.m).

Answer (score 4):

What you said on twitter does not match your question.

If you are having memory spikes, look at Instruments to figure out what is consuming the memory.   Just the data alone for your high resolution image is 10 megs, and your resulting images are going to be about 750k, if they contain no alpha channel.

The first issue is keeping the memory usage low, for that, make sure that all of the images that you load are disposed as soon as you are done using them, that will ensure that the underlying C/Objective-C API disposes the memory immediately, instead of waiting for the GC to run, so something like:

```
 using (var img = UIImage.FromFile ("..."){
     using (var scaled = Scaler (img)){
          scaled.Save (...);
     }
 }
```

As for the scaling, there are a variety of ways of scaling the images.   The simplest way is to create a context, then draw on it, and then get the image out of the context.    This is how MonoTouch's UIImage.Scale method is implemented:

```
public UIImage Scale (SizeF newSize)
{
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (newSize);

    Draw (new RectangleF (0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));

    var scaledImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;            
}
```

The performance will be governed by the context features that you enable.   For example, a higher-quality scaling would require changing the interpolation quality:

```
 context.InterpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.High
```

The other option is to run your scaling not on the CPU, but on the GPU.   To do that, you would use the CoreImage API and use the CIAffineTransform filter.

As to which one is faster, it is something left for someone else to benchmark

```
CGImage Scale (string file)
{
    var ciimage = CIImage.FromCGImage (UIImage.FromFile (file));

    // Create an AffineTransform that makes the image 1/5th of the size
    var transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (0.5f, 0.5f);

    var affineTransform = new CIAffineTransform () { 
        Image = ciimage,
        Transform = transform
    };
    var output = affineTransform.OutputImage;
    var context = CIContext.FromOptions (null);
    return context.CreateCGImage (output, output.Extent);
}
```

Comment: Hey Miguel, thanks for taking time to write this answer. I'm sorry if my tweets were misleading. Instruments revealed that even though I dispose the objects right away, there may be 4 or 5 images resizing in background threads that contribute to memory spikes. I will write a custom Task scheduler to disallow too many memory-hungry threads at once but I was curious if I could resize images *without loading them fully in memory in the first place*, disk-to-disk, so to speak.

Comment: mem map... [NSData initWithContentsOfFile
          :?path?:NSDataReadingUncached:nil];

Answer (score 3):

If either is more efficient of the two then it'll be the former.

When you create a `CGImageSource` you create just what the name says — some sort of opaque thing from which an image can be obtained. In your case it'll be a reference to a thing on disk. When you ask ImageIO to create a thumbnail you explicitly tell it "do as much as you need to output this many pixels".

Conversely if you draw to a `CGBitmapContext` then at some point you explicitly bring the whole image into memory.

So the second approach definitely has the whole image in memory at once at some point. Conversely the former needn't necessarily (in practice there'll no doubt be some sort of guesswork within ImageIO as to the best way to proceed). So across all possible implementations of the OS either the former will be advantageous or there'll be no difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I would try using a c-based library like leptonica. I'm not sure whether ios optimizes Core Graphics with the relatively new Accelerate Framework, but CoreGraphics probably has more overhead involved just to re-size an image. Finally... If you want to roll your own implementation try using vImageScale_??format?? backed with some memory mapped files, I can't see anything being faster.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/Introduction/Introduction.html

PS. Also make sure to check the compiler optimization flags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting here. As I mentioned in my bounty note, “I'm looking for an answer backed by actual research/great knowledge of API—just guessing doesn't cut it”.

Comment: I'm pretty sure vImageScale w/ a mem map would be the speed limit, doesn't take much work to experiment with it.  The next fastest is a raw spaced read from a mem map directed to a new buffer, but that would get complicated with different image sizes, and look bad.

Comment: Probably useful...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068095/uiimage-become-fuzzy-when-it-was-scaled-whyios-5-0

Comment: [That](https://github.com/dhoerl/PhotoScrollerNetwork/blob/master/PhotoScroller/Classes/TiledImageBuilder%2BJPEG.m)'s impressive. (Found this in the question you linked to.)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to save the memory you can read the source image from tile to tile and compress the tile and save to the destination tile.

There is an example from apple. It is the implementation of the way.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html

You can download this project and run it. It is MRC so you can use it very smoothly.

May it help. :)